# Do i need HTTPS for Administration Panel? Best way to secure it in node.js?

Tags: node.js, security, https

I am developing a small website with a custom admin page that allow to simply modify and insert contents.

This is how it works: in domain.com/admin there is a page with an autentication form. Of course the only user that know the password is the admin (not me, my client). If the password is right, server send an html page that allow to modify the content of the website. How? Dynamic information are stored in a mongodb database setted up on localhost of server. So, using simple CRUD operation like insert, update and remove, the content of the website will change. In the clientside i simply do same "post" requests to the server, wich makes CRUD operations.

I need to make this system safe. Do i need https for autentication? Do you think that a simple autentication password for admin would be enougth? And what about the way i check if the passwords matches? I was thinking to store the admin password in the database (that have a password too) but maybe is unuseful. i could simply compare two strings cause the password is only one, there are no other registered users different by admin. But i'm not sure, this seems unsafe :D Any idea for the best way to do it??

I'm using node js (NO express). I have a dedicated root VPS.

Answer (score 0):

https will be better, and you can just keep the salt and hash code in database instead of keeping the password directly. likely most of website have a feature to reset password not find the password, they don't keep password directly in file. when someone know the salt and hash code , they can't reverse the password.